# Weights in adaboost/decision tree(cart)

Tags: random-forest, cart, entropy, adaboost

I'm trying to implement adaboost using decision trees. But I'm confused over the weights. I am unable to understand how to incorporate weights in training process, how the formulas for node entropy and information gain will change. Also when a leaf node is reached then how the prediction is done is it also weighted somehow or is it just on pure probability of positive and negative sample points in the leaf node..?
And does the  adaboost aims to reduce the train error to produce better test results?